# How to distribute a sum across multiple entities in the most "tax-effective" way

Tags: linear-algebra

**Context:** I'm designing a tool for a Financial Modelling program which distributes a Trust's income to its beneficiaries in the most tax-effective manner.

**Variables:**

- John's salary is `$80,000`
- Mary's salary is `$60,000`
- Paul's salary is `$70,000`
- Faye's salary is `$90,000`

`s` is equal to the sum of all salaries (`s = 300,000`)

`c` is the number of individuals (`c = 4`)

A Trust generates `p` in profit which must be distributed to the individuals in the most tax-effective manner. This is achieved by **minimising** and **levelling** the individuals' income as best possible.

**Scenario 1: the Trust generates `p = $100,000` in profit**

- Add `$20,000` to John's income: `80,000 + 20,000 = 100,000`
- Add `$40,000` to Mary's income: `80,000 + 40,000 = 100,000`
- Add `$30,000` to Paul's income: `80,000 + 30,000 = 100,000`
- Add `$10,000` to Faye's income: `80,000 + 10,000 = 100,000`

Using the formula `((s + p) / c) - [individual's salary]` I can solve scenario 1, distributing the entire profit in the most tax-effective manner.

**Scenario 2: the Trust generates `p = $50,000` in profit**
This is where I'm lost. I know through manual calcs in Excel that the following is the desired result, but I can't figure out a formula to achieve this outcome.

- Add `$6,666.67` to John's income: `80,000 + 6,666.67 = 86,666.67`
- Add `$26,666.67` to Mary's income: `80,000 + 26,666.67 = 86,666.67`
- Add `$16,666.67` to Paul's income: `80,000 + 16,666.67 = 86,666.67`
- Add `$0` to Faye's income: `90,000 + 0 = 90,000`

**Question:**

Is there a formula which satisfies both scenarios, with the following considerations?

- No subtracting from one person's income to give to another
- The salaries, number of individuals, and profits are all variable
- The entire profit **must** be distributed

**More background, not important**
This tool was originally designed to work with a constant 2 individuals, which made the distribution formula:

`(p - ([john's salary] - [mary's salary])) / 2` to get John's share of the profit

`(p - ([mary's salary] - [john's salary])) / 2` to get Mary's share of the profit

Apologies for any misuse or poor formatting - math is <sub>evidently</sub> not my domain and I figured this sort of question was best asked here. Cheers.